# Plot doesn't appear after using plt.plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import plt

abc = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',]

def countp(counter):
    count=0
    for i in counter:
        print(abc[count],"showed up ",i," times")
        count+=1

def checkfile(folder):     
    file = open(folder,"r")
    read=file
    abc = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',]
    counter = [0]*26
    #read file
    for i in file:
        # reads line
        for j in i:
            count=0
            #search one key at a time
            for k in abc:
                if (j==k.lower()):
                    #add +1 to desired letter. 
                    counter[count]+=1
                count+=1
    return counter

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder="C:/Users/omerd/Desktop/Welp.txt"
    counter=checkfile(folder)
    countp(counter)
    x=5
    y=6
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

it does run, but it doesn't use the

```
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

line. It should open a chart, but it doesn't, not sure if newbie mistake or need to reinstall everything.

Comment: have a look at `collections.Counter`, why do you have 2 `abc` variables, look at the `strings` module, use context managers `with open(...) as file:`

Answer (score 2):

Many Documentations Don't mention this but try adding `plt.show()` at the after `plt.plot()`.
`plt.show()` is just to open the matplotlib plot

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to add `plt.show()` at the end of your code. This will display your plot.

From matplotlib's official [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html): *When running in ipython with its pylab mode, display all figures and return to the ipython prompt.*